# How to add multiple keyframe animations on the same property

Tags: animation, keyframes

I am new to blender, and I want to create a cabinet. Now I add an animation called `open-door` that rotate around the z-axis 0deg to 172deg.
I want add another animation called `door-close`, but don't know how to add it.

I using key `I` to add keyframe, but rotation z already have a keyframe, I press I again, the previous keyframe will be overwritten.

Hope i can make it clear. Very very thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the Dope Sheet switch to Action Editor and create an other action.

Comment: @FFeller Thank you,  fllow your guide my problem was solved now